# Finding the best and worst O()

Tags: algorithm, big-o

Using the following algorithm, im trying to determine the best and worst O().

```
minCoin(total, C[]) {
    if (total == 0) {return 0}
    min = MAX_VALUE
    for (i in C.length) {
        if (C[i] > total) {continue}
        value = minCoin(total - C[i], C)
        if (value < min) {min = value}
    }
    min = MAX_VALUE ? min : min++
    return min
}
```

Best: O(1) because if total == 0, well return
Worst: O(nT) because n = the number of coins in the array, and T = the total we are making.

I also thought that the worst case could be O(2^n) where n is the number of recursive calls.

Is that correct?

Comment: what's purpose of "min = MAX_VALUE ? min..." ? It's always min = min

Comment: min retures 0. but, i can just return min+1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently the complexity is about O(2^n).So it is exponential .
But if you convert it to dynamic programming by memoization the complexity will be O(nT).

Solving by dynamic Programming :

```
memoization[total]={-1}// initially every index holds -1
minCoin(total, C[]) {
    if (total == 0) {return 0}

    if(memoization[total]!=-1) return memoization[total]; 
    min = MAX_VALUE
    for (i in C.length) {
        if (C[i] > total) {continue}
        value = minCoin(total - C[i], C)
        if (value < min) {min = value}
    }
    min = MAX_VALUE ? min : min++
    return memoization[total]=min 
}
```

once we calculated for total we change the value of memoization of total from -1 to its result . So if we get total again we will just return memoization[total] as we stored the result on it before.

For details about DP:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming/

Comment: Would you mind giving me an example of this in DP by memoization? if thats not too much to ask for.

Comment: @soldfor I have converted your problem to DP. Please see the example

Comment: by memoization, doesnt look much different

Comment: If you find my answer helpful please upvote it ! Thanks !